# Каким образом зафиксировать один аргумент в функции C++?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, typedef

У меня есть 2 типа функций:

```
typedef double (*func_t1)(double x);
typedef double (*func_t2)(double x, double y);
```

Я хочу получить вот такую функцию:

```
func_t1 GetFunc(func_t2 f, double y)
{
    double func(double x)
    {
        return f(x, y);
    }
    return func;
}
```

Я понимаю что написал здесь бред. Но смысл в том, что мне нужно в функцию GetFunc подать:

1. Функцию из двух аргументов (f)
2. Второй аргумент для этой функции (y)

А на выходе я должен получить функцию из одного аргумента (func).

```
func_t1 func = GetFunc(f, 5);    
func(1); // Это f(1, 5);
```

Comment: В чем цель? Для удобства, чтобы не писать каждый раз второй параметр? Или чтобы передать результат куда-то, где нужен указатель на функцию с одним параметром?

Comment: такая функция есть. Называется std::bind, раньше были ещё std::bind2nd, который делал ровно то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim `std::bind` ничего подобного не делает

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Я реализую метод гаусса для минимизации функции нескольких переменных. В функции из двух переменных мне нужно временно заморозить один параметр. Мне действительно нужен указатель на функцию с одним параметром.

Comment: @KoVadim Вообще то std::bind мне очень подходит, спасибо)

Comment: @ВячеславСысоев Ага, вот только он не возвращает указатель на функцию. Он возвращает объект класса с перегруженным оператором `()`, который притворяется функцией.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужны именно обычные функции?

Comment: Меня устроит закос под функции)

Comment: ¿Ну а зачем тогда писать в вопросе *"А на выходе я должен получить функцию из одного аргумента"* и вводить читателей вопроса в заблуждение? Если нужен закос, то используйте лямбда выражения и все..

Comment: *"действительно нужен указатель на функцию"* -> *"устроит закос под функции"* :Р

Comment: С `bind`-ом (или с лямбдой, без разницы) вам потребуется `std::function` вместо указателя на функцию. Но вообще, странно видеть такое в математическом коде: `std::function` не бесплатный, у него есть оверхед. Вместо того чтобы пытаться добиться красивого синтаксиса, лучше положить значение второго аргумента в какую-нибудь переменную и каждый раз ее передавать.

Comment: Сори, что так сформулировал вопрос в конце, не сильно шарю за плюсы и его std, я больше по си. Но саму суть вопроса я передал в заголовке "Зафиксировать аргумент", конкретно тут bind мне идеально подошла. Я понимаю что std::function не бесплатный, но тут архитектурно оч сложно сделать по другому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать не указатели на функции (которые не могут принимать некоторые типы, например лямбды с захваченными данными), а `std::function`

```
using func_t1 = std::function<double( double )>;
using func_t2 = std::function<double( double, double )>;
```

теперь можно преобразовывать, как вам нужно:

```
double f2( double x, double y )
{
    std::cout << "f2(" << x << "," << y << ")" << std::endl;
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    double fixed = 123;
    // используем лямбду
    func_t1 fa = [fixed]( double x ) { return f2( x, fixed ); };
    // используем std::bind
    func_t1 fb = std::bind( f2, _1, fixed );
    fa( 1 );
    fb( 2 );
}
```

[Живой пример](https://ideone.com/4Od3KG)

Конечно, вы должны понимать, что использование `std::function` имеет накладные расходы

Замечание: переменная `fixed` в приведенном коде будет скопирована, те ее изменение после создания лямбды или вызова `std::bind` не изменит аргумента. Если же вам нужно менять аргумент, то в лямда нужно использовать `&fixed`, а в `std::bind` - `std::ref( fixed )`. При этом следует помнить, что время жизни переменной должно быть соотвественным и не короче, чем функторы, которые вы используете, иначе вы получите невалидную ссылку.

Comment: Замечание к замечанию. Захват переменной по ссылке не продляет её время жизни, поэтому его следует использовать осторожно

Comment: @AlexGuteniev спасибо, справедливое замечание, добавлю к ответу, если не возражаете